# How do you phpunit test redirection to urls with extra (dynamic) parameters?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

In L4.2, I have been trying to use the phpunit helpers `assertRedirectedToRoute()` or `assertRedirectedToAction()`, but they don’t work when there are additional optional params put on the url.

For instance, I have this route:

```
Route::get('properties/create/{step?}/{property_id?}', [
        'as' => 'admin.properties.createStep',
        'uses' => 'PropertiesController@createStep']);
```

However, `$this->assertRedirectedToAction(‘App\Controllers\PropertiesController@createStep’)` fails with the following response:

```
1) AdminPropertiesTest::testSearchPostDataWithoutEANPropertyId
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'http://localhost/admin/properties/create'
+'http://localhost/admin/properties/create/3/194921'
```

How do I get an assertion to pass without declaring the "3" or "194921" in the url (as they are dynamic) and using `assertRedirectedTo()`?